# Is there a way to set variables for NSObjects without creating properties for each?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Basically, I have a custom NSObject with a lot of boolean variables. I would like to know if there is a way to modify these variables (from outside this class) without creating a property for each one. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!
Here is part of my object's header:

```
@interface Polygons : NSObject {

//BOOL values for attributes
BOOL parallelogram;
BOOL rhombus;
BOOL square;

...

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a bitmask to represent a set of related boolean properties. First, define an enum like so:

```
enum GeometryFlags {
    Parallelogram = 1 << 0,
    Rhombus       = 1 << 1,
    Square        = 1 << 2,

    // etc.
};
```

You can optionally provide a corresponding typedef statement:

```
typedef NSUInteger GeometryFlags;
```

Then you can define a property to allow outside callers to access the bitmask:

```
// In .h file:
@property (nonatomic) GeometryFlags geometryFlags;

// In .m file:
@synthesize geometryFlags = _geometryFlags;
```

Calling code can then access the property to get or set the bitfield. Note that you can use the bitwise OR operator to specify multiple values:

```
// Uses the property accessor to modify two values in the bitmask.
someObj.geometryFlags = Parallelogram | Rhombus;
```

### EDIT

For more info on how to work with a bitmask, see the following:

[How do those bitmasks actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555101/how-do-those-bitmasks-actually-work)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: Thanks for the idea! However I am unfamiliar with both bitfields and enums. Could you please provide a link where I can read up on them? Thanks again!

Comment: @Garrett In retrospect, I should've said 'bitmask' rather than 'bitfield'. I've updated my answer accordingly, and also added some links for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! that makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with KVC, e.g.:

```
BOOL isParallelogram = [[myPolygon valueForKey:@"parallelogram"] boolValue];
```

(see [Accessor Search Implementation Details](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html) in the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide)

That said, I wouldn't recommend this approach. Not only is it inefficient, but it also breaks [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). This is exactly what properties are made for and there's no reason not to use them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just create a method which takes the name of the variable and the value and then assigns it to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them `@public`:

```
@interface Polygons : NSObject {
@public
//BOOL values for attributes
BOOL parallelogram;
BOOL rhombus;
BOOL square;
...
```

and then access them like this:

```
mypolygon->square = NO;
```

However, this breaks encapsulation, as @omz explained.

---

You could write a simple script that generates the properties for you. Here's a starting point:

```
grep "BOOL [a-zA-Z0-9_]+;$" Polygons.h
```

Comment: thank you for the response and the suggestion, i will probably end up writing that script

Comment: Also note that when using the -> operator, your app will crash if the polygon is nil.